# CoreBluetooth: iPhone as HID peripheral

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth

I just started to program an app for iPhone (BT 4.0 LE). The iPhone is going to be the peripheral device. The central could be a MAC or PC.

Do I have to write an "App" for MAC and/or PC? Or will it simply run without?

iPhone service is HID (0x1812).

( More details about the service/characteristics: 
http://developer.bluetooth.org/gatt/services/Pages/ServiceViewer.aspx?u=org.bluetooth.service.human_interface_device.xml )

Thank you

Comment: "Peripheral device" for what use?

Comment: For HID Input like mouse or keyboard.

Comment: That is a really cool idea! I would imagine that you'd be implementing an iOS app that advertised itself as a Bluetooth keyboard or mouse. Consequently, I wouldn't expect that you'd need a Mac/PC app to go along with it.

Comment: @mharper: Thank you. I'm just about to learn Bluetooth implementation in iOS. I already understood that I don't have to write an App for the central device by using Bluetooth standard UUID's. I also know that I have to learn a lot to finish my App. I'm just waiting for the next WWDC. May there will be some changes in CoreBluetooth that will ease my work.

Comment: Bluetooth and Bluetooth LE are almost entirely different things that happen to share most of a name. I don't think Bluetooth LE supports HID.